# Layout Problems  with Open GL SurfaceView after phone is locked

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-layout

I am running an app with a SurfaceView.  When the Surface view is visible and I press the 'power' button to lock the phone then return to the app the perspective is off.  It appears to be rendering a "tall and skinny" view on the left side of my "short and wide" view.

When I look at onSurfaceChanged it is being called once when the phone is powered on with 'width=480 height=800' then again when after the phone is unlocked with 'width=800 height=480'.  I am calling gl.glFrustumf() each frame with the correct new width/height data collected from onSurfaceChanged but something is still making my window appear skinny and tall, any ideas?

Edit:
Perhaps it has something to do with my view structure.

The Activities contentView is called MainView..

```
         MainView
        /        \
     UIView     SurfaceView (I look wrong)
     /
UI Elements
(These all look correct)
```

Edit #2:

Screenshot:

[image: LockScreenFail]

The globe and the 'Download More' button are drawn in 3d.  The Square in is a child of the UI view (other children of UIView also show up correctly).  It appears as if the SurfaceView thinks the width is the height and the height is the width.  I did more printing of the Surface View's Width and height and get this output:

```
--Phone On Unlock Screen
--Activity onWindowFocusChanged called
I/System.out( 8817): ***********UI Width: 480 UI Height: 800
I/System.out( 8817): ***********Main Width: 480 Main Height: 800
I/System.out( 8817): ***********GL Width: 480 GL Height: 800

--App continues to run. These are triggered in GLSurfaceView onLayout
I/System.out( 8061): ***********UI Width: 800 UI Height: 480
I/System.out( 8061): ***********Main Width: 800 Main Height: 480
I/System.out( 8061): ***********GL Width: 800 GL Height: 480

I/System.out( 8061): ***********UI Width: 800 UI Height: 480
I/System.out( 8061): ***********Main Width: 800 Main Height: 480
I/System.out( 8061): ***********GL Width: 800 GL Height: 480
```

So the Width and Height appear to fix themselves sometime after onWindowFocusChanged but graphically it never looks correct.

Edit #3:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {  

}
```

:)

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    mWidth = width;
    mHeight = height;

    mAspectRatio = (float) width / height;  
    mSurfaceChangedID++;
}
```

Then I since I have something ideas rendered in 3d and others as 2d UI elements I setup the projection each frame in the onDraw

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

    gl.glClearColor( mClearColorR, mClearColorG, mClearColorB, 1.0f );
    gl.glClear( GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    for( each item ) {

        if( item.Is3d() ) {
            //For 3d Elements:
            gl.glMatrixMode( GL10.GL_PROJECTION );
            gl.glLoadIdentity();                    
            gl.glFrustumf( mAspectRatio*-mHalfViewAngleTan, mAspectRatio*mHalfViewAngleTan, -mHalfViewAngleTan, mHalfViewAngleTan, mNearZClip, mFarZClip );                  

            //Enable Lighting, Setup fog
            ...

        } else {
            //For UI Elements:

            gl.glMatrixMode( GL10.GL_PROJECTION );
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            gl.glOrthof( -0.5f*mAspectRatio, 0.5f*mAspectRatio, -0.5f, 0.5f, -1, 1 );

            //Disable Lighting, Disable fog, Setup blending
            ...
        }

        //Setup client state and vertex buffers
        ...

        gl.glDrawArrays( GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, mdl.getVtxCount() );  
    }
}
```

Edit #4:

Turns out it did have to do with View, I changed how the SurfaceView was added to its parent...

It was...

```
getMainView().addView( m3DView );
```

It is now...

```
    // add to parent view
    {
        Display display = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        android.widget.AbsoluteLayout absLayout = new android.widget.AbsoluteLayout(this);
        absLayout.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight()));
        absLayout.addView( m3DView, new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight()) );
        getMainView().addView( absLayout );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GLSurfaceView must be notified when the activity is paused and resumed. GLSurfaceView clients are required to call onPause() when the activity pauses and onResume() when the activity resumes. These calls allow GLSurfaceView to pause and resume the rendering thread, and also allow GLSurfaceView to release and recreate the OpenGL display.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: I was already calling onPause and onResume, didn't seem to change much :-\  I did find out that if after unlocking the phone I print the SurfaceView's getWidth and getHeight it comes back as w=480 h=800 instead of the other way around so I feel like I am managing the view incorrectly.

Comment: ah..sorry..I really missed the point. Could you post a screenshot to show what you mean by "skinny and tall"

Comment: Aha..ok, now it is more clear. I am assuming the next points(let me know if not): onSurfaceChanged is called after phone was unlocked with correct w and h(at least second time). Are you setting up your projection in onSurfaceChanged? If not than you should. I am a bit guessing here...could you also post the code for onSurfaceCreated and onSurfaceChnaged. +also code in onDraw related to viewport and cameras

Comment: Yes the projection code was my first suspect too but I couldn't find anything wrong with it.  I added it above.

Comment: I am more convinced it has something to do with the Android Views now.  Similar bad-ness happens if I lock and unlock during our intro movie, which uses no OpenGL code.  It also appears if I change activities and return things are working.